# AWS initial setup scripts

Tags: amazon-web-services

So I have setup my aws environment, EKS and RDS, but on deployment I ran into a problem which given the fact that am new to aws, have not been able to figure out. I want to run initial scripts like DB schema setup, DB seeding, I have been struggling with this and frankly I haven't gotten anywhere, do I have to create a separate EC2 instance to be able to do that. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Run those scripts where? Sadly its not clear how do you create your EKS and RDS? In AWS console, terraform, cloudfomration? Some CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: Can you elaborate on these two:
1. What is the problem that you are running into?
2. How did you set up EKS and RDS? Through Web Console or using some IAC mechanism?
Also you shouldn't be needing to spin up an EC2 to setup anything in AWS, you should be able to do it from your machine / some machine as long as you have aws credentials configured properly.

Comment: Ok as I have said, am new to this kind of setup, I created the services basically using console on the web, so the main problem I have is creating database schema and running database seeds, and basically wonder how do I do that, @PraveenSastry can you kindly show me how I can do it from my machine?

Comment: Also @Marcin I have those scripts in a docker container so its basically running the container with a `--rm` flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this guide to configure aws credentials locally (and use it with their cli) following the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

Once you configure your credentials, you can do something like this to share the local credentials with the docker container that is running your scripts.

```
docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws -v $(pwd):/aws <image_name>:<tag>
```